# How to share current page Url in expo React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am currently building a React Native mobile app using expo. I want  to share my current location on app with my fiends to whatsapp and faebook and instagram. so when they tap on my message or post they will redirect to app page on same location on my app which i share. same as instagram posts are share on facebook and also youtube vedio url share on whatsapp, facebook...
I want to implement that process on my app how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

In your app's router you can add the route as part of the shared message. That way when people click on it, it will direct them to the same route/"current location".